# Java Web Start Application Stopped Working for Chrome Browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, web, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a Java Web Start application that suddenly stopped working when I try to instantiate it via accessing my web application with a Chrome browser. Previously, Chrome had allowed me to "keep" my JNLP then run it from the download bar; now it "spins" for a little while, making you think it's downloading the JNLP file, but nothing happens in the end, i.e., no "keep or discard" message, no "application blocked" message, and nothing in the Java console...

I've read there's a limit to how many times you can download the same JNLP file, but I don't recall the number. At any rate, I deleted all copies of my JNLP file from my download folder, but it hasn't made a difference. What needs to be done to get Chrome back to downloading my JNLP file?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Chrome to launch your JNLP automatically:

1. Launch Chrome, and install the latest version of the Java plug-in for Chrome, if you don’t currently have it (see Resources).
2. Close Chrome and restart it.
3. Navigate to the Web or intranet location, and click on the link containing the JNLP file. The file should download and show up in your download bar at the bottom of the screen.
4. Click the down arrow next to the JNLP file and click “Always open files of this type.”

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/configure-chrome-open-jnlp-files-56623.html

Comment: Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Will do, @pruntlar, but I have some unrelated development work to complete in another part of the application first, so it might be a couple days. But since my customer-service co-worker would dearly love to have us avoid the Chrome JWS two-step :), I will definitely look into and let you if it helped us in that respect